# Creating two strings from one

Tags: c

Is there a way I can create two strings without the second one containing the first?

I currently have this

```
char * s = "Generic String";
char foo[1];
memcpy(foo, s, 1);
char bar[2];
memcpy(bar, s, 2);
printf("%s %s\n", foo, bar);
```

which will print out G GeG

Clearly I'd like it to print G Ge.

Answer (score 2):

All strings in C needs an end marker - i.e. the null character.

So the code

```
char foo[1];
```

Should be

```
char foo[2];
```

Followed by

```
foo[0] = s[0];
foo[1] = 0;
```

Ditto for the other one.

i.e.

```
char bar[3];
memcpy(bar, s, 2); /* As you prefer */
bar[2] = 0; /* To terminate the string */
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to NUL-terminate the strings. Currently your program invokes undefined behavior. Also, use `const char *` or `char []` when initializing from a string literal, else const correctness is broken.

```
const char *s = "Generic String";

char foo[2];
memcpy(foo, s, 1);
foo[1] = 0;

char bar[3];
memcpy(bar, s, 2);
bar[2] = 0;

printf("%s %s\n", foo, bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using strings without zero at the end.

Options 1: restrict printing width:

```
printf("%*s %*s\n", 1, foo, 2, bar);
```

Option 2: allocate space for string terminators (0).

```
char foo[2];
char bar[3];

memcpy(foo, s, 1);
foo[1] = 0;
memcpy(bar, s, 2);
bar[2] = 0;
```